# Change Replace keyboard shortcut in Gedit

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm a Linux user trying to get used to Mac. I've already swapped the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> keys around.

I'm using Gedit in Mac now, and the replace key combination I'm used to (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>) is hiding the Window.

I've been using Karabiner to remap keys, and have been trying to figure out private.xml syntax to remap this how I want it to behave.

Here's what I have so far (not working):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
     <name>Change Control-H (Command-H Hide in Mac) to Replace for gEdit (Control-Alt-F)</name>
     <identifier>private.control_h_to_replace</identifier>
     <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, VK_COMMAND,KeyCode::F</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

I've also tried to remap it using Mac's settings > keyboard > shortcuts.

The Mac keyboard is driving me batty.

Comment: Please sanitize your question. You are mixing cmd-H and ctrl-H in the headline and the body as well as in the xml file. ctrl-H (on an Apple keyboard) doesn't hide anything!

Comment: Thanks - I cannot sanitize what I don't understand, I guess... I have already swapped my command and control keys around.... does that change anything?

Comment: If you don't mention that you already swapped the ctrl and the cmd key in Karabiner - which is impossible to guess based on your question, we can't give a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for Karabiner is off.

This will work. Note that, like @klanomath, I have no idea if you're actually trying to use <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, so you may need to change `COMMAND_L` to `CONTROL_L` on the third line.

```
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::H, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::F, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
        </autogen>
```

It also now occurs to me that in your version, within the code, your replacement command is <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> as opposed to <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> as specified in the `name`. So you might need to adjust `CONTROL_L` to `COMMAND_L` on the fourth line.

Comment: Thanks, @tubedogg - I did need to change CONTROL_L to COMMAND_L.

Comment: You might also want to replace `COMMAND_L` on the 3rd line with this: `MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND` (in case you don't always use the left Command key to hit H).